# Updating product image

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I have been having this problem recently, I want to update quite a few product images on my website with updated versions.

I save the image with the exact same name and upload via FTP to my server, to my understanding it is either going to replace the current image or create a duplicate( save the image name with a -1 e.g. Ap2018-1). But neither of that happens. Both images are there with the exact same name but the old image is still being used.

Comment: "_Both images are there with the exact same name but the old image is still being used._" - Literally cannot be true :)

Answer (score 0):

Propably you replace only original versions of images, but wordpress create a few this same images with different sizes.

After upload your photos you should regenerate thumbnails on wordpress dashboard.

You can use for it:
https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

or little advanced: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails-advanced/

When you regenerated thumbnails, images should be correctly displayed.